# how to get string from EditText every time onClick in loop?

Tags: android, android-edittext

The question is the title. I want to get string from EditText everytime on while, like in C++...........................................................................................................................................................

```
    while(viso!=x){
        z = rand.nextInt(x)+1;
        rodoma.setText("koks sio zodzio vertimas? : "+ str1.elementAt(z));

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get string from EditText priimti;
                }
                }
     );

        if(onClick(value)==str2.elementAt(z)){
            str1.remove(z);
            str2.remove(z);
            rodoma1.setText("zodis teisingas");
            viso++;
        }else{
            rodoma1.setText("zodis yra : "+ str2.elementAt(z));
        }
    }

    }

private String onClick(String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: you need to get the text from edittext on button click unless you have the text set for edittext in xml

Comment: Yes i want to get the text on button click everytime in loop

Comment: why do you require a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set an OnClickListener in a while. You can set it outside and save the text in a variable. Then you can use the variable's value inside the while. Your code should look like this.

```
Marked as solved, because of the comments.
```

Comment: Program crashes, because, i think, its infinite loop, i need, that every time loop waits for the answer and then checks it

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are thinking as if you were programming in C++, but in Java, you don't need to use a while. You have listeners for everything. I am updating my answer with a different approach that may help you.

Comment: ohhh yesss, now i get it, i can do this without loop, thanks, i was just thinking as c++ programmer would :D

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the answer as correct if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
String str = EditTextObject.getText();
```

That should return the string inside the edit text.

Comment: `getText()` returns a Editable type. You will get a type mismatch error. Your code should be `String str = editTextObject.getText().toString();`